# Why changing a property of an entity in entity framework does not applied?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have an entity that has a property named `Status`. I am using the following code in order to change the status of the records in an entity framework repository. But after running the method, no changes are applied to the database. this method is inside a repository class.

```
public void RemoveTempSet(IEnumerable<Guid> viewIds)
{
        foreach (var id in viewIds)
        {
            var entity = this.Get(id);

            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.Status = Enums.Status.Bin;
            }
        }

        Save();
}
```

Why SaveChanges method of the entity framework does not work?

P.S. If you need more information, please tell me in commends. Thanks.

Comment: It fixed! the problem was the Blog project had an old version of Enums.Systems dll !